# Inserting and shifting rows in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, insert

According to the Matlab profiler, the following two operations take the most time in my code.

---

I have a matrix A that I always keep a fixed size (`N` rows and `2` columns). I  have to remove the first row consisting of two real-valued numbers, shift all rows up by one and insert `[ Inf Inf ]` as the last row. I do not understand why the following line is so slow.

```
A = [ A(2:end,:) ; [ Inf Inf ] ];
```

---

The second problem I encounter is when I simultaneously need to insert a row into the same matrix A and remove the last row. Let us assume that I want to insert `row` at row `idx`. Then the following line considerably slows down the code.

```
A = [ A(1:(idx - 1),:) ; row ; A(idx:(end - 1),:) ];
```

---

Any idea why the two similar operations are slow? I do understand that slow is relative, but it might be that such operations are bad practice and I can improve on them.

Comment: What is the size of N?
And how much time does it takes?

Comment: It is slow because you are modifying the data requiring the *entire* matrix  to be copied in memory. For large matrices this can be very slow.

Comment: Is this any faster: `A(1:end-1) = A(2:end); A(end,:) = Inf`? i.e. doing the operation in-place?

Comment: You could also try [`circshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) and just overwrite the last line: `A = circshift(A, -1, 1); A(end,:) = Inf;` From a very quick test it seems ~2x faster than the current & @Dan's method for 50k rows. For the second part, I'm not understanding why you can't just overwrite the row: `A(idx,:) = row;`

Comment: `N` is arbitrary, but not large, say 10. I have to call it 10^6 times though. From a very brief test, it seems that the method of @Dan is not faster. I will try the method @excaza proposed now for the first part. For the second part, I cannot overwrite the row, I need to make space by moving all rows at or above row `idx` up by one and discard the last row.

Comment: @excaza Unfortunately, also `circshift` seems to be just as slow as what I had in the opening post.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I have a 2-3x speed improvement for 50k rows in R2016a.

Comment: @excaza R2014b. For 50k rows I get the same improvement. However, I am working with far fewer rows, see my comment above.

Comment: @ritz maybe explain why you need to do it, perhaps there is a way to avoid this entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Both operations result in building a new matrix of size nx2 and copying the contents of the old one into the new one. In both cases O(n) operations are done. That's not ideal, especially in a tight loop.

If you're doing it for every row of the data, that an O(nˆ2) operation. You'll start running into problems even for smallish ns like 10k or 100k.

Answer (score 1):

After the warm-up, this kind of gets 1.5-2 times faster most of the time, for your first question (on 2016a).

```
N = 10;
M = rot90(blkdiag(rot90(eye(N-1)),inf),-1);
ind = 10000;
t = zeros(ind,1);
indarr = 1:ind;

for i = indarr
    A = rand(N,2);
    B = rand(N,2);

    tic,A = [ A(2:end,:) ; [ Inf Inf ] ];t1=toc;
    tic,B = M*B;t2 = toc;

    t(i) = t1-t2;
end

plot(t)
```